# Cost of std::vector::push_back either succeeding or having no effect?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

If I understand correctly, [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) does not guarantee a commit-or-rollback for [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s (it does for `std::list`s for obvious reasons) in the case an exception is thrown during copying or moving, because of the high cost of checking for exceptions. I recently saw that `push_back` DOES guarantee either successful insertion at the end or nothing happens.

My question is the following. Suppose that during a `push_pack` the vector has to be resized (reallocation happens). In that case, all elements have to be copied in the new container, via copy or move semantics. Assuming that the move constructor is not guaranteed `noexcept`, `std::vector` will then use copy semantics. So, to guarantee the above behaviour of `push_pack`, `std::vector` has to check for successful copying, and if not, roll back via a swap the initial vector. Is this what is happening, and if so, isn't this expensive? Or, because reallocation happens rarely, one can say that the amortized cost is low?

Comment: actually since C++11 a vector doesn't simply falls back to a copy ctor if the move ctor is not noexcept. Read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back under **Exceptions** . the copy ctor is 1 of the 2 options in that case .

Comment: @user2485710: Are you referring to cases where `T` is non-copyable? Well, yes, obviously, in that case, the copy constructor will not be used, as it does not exist. But if it *does* exist, then it will be used.

Comment: @user2485710 hmm, ok, it says that if move may throw, then the operation is no longer guaranteed to succeed/nothing happen (" If it throws, the guarantee is waived and the effects are unspecified."). I am reading about this from the Josuttis' book on STL, and he says something different (basically what I wrote), see pg. 279. I am a bit confused, as cppreference.com is not actually the standard and, in sec. 23.2.1/11 of the standard, `push_back` is also guaranteed.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the requirement is less generic then "copyable" or "non-copyable". Anyway I can't see the point of this honestly; why a guy want's to know this ? To do what ? To care about what ?

Comment: @vsoftco: A sidenote; When reallocating, the vector can wait setting the internal data pointer to the new array until the data has been copied succesfully. There's no need to swap it on exception.

Comment: @user2079303 ok, yes, my bad, but still needs to check the copying.

Comment: @vsoftco I believe so. Otherwise the incomplete data would always leak on exception.

Comment: Thanks all for the useful comments!

Comment: You might be interested in that talk : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C++98/03 we (obviously) had no move semantics, only copy semantics.  And in C++98/03, `push_back` has the strong guarantee.  One of the strong motivations in C++11 was to not break existing code that relied on this strong guarantee.

The C++11 rules are:

1. If `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is true, move, else
2. If `is_copy_constructible<T>::value` is true, copy, else
3. If `is_move_constructible<T>::value` is true, move, else
4. The code is ill-formed.

If we are in the case of 1 or 2, we have the [strong guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).  If we are in case 3, we have only the [basic guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).  Since in C++98/03, we were always in case 2, we have backwards compatibility.

Case 2 is not expensive to maintain the strong guarantee.  One allocates the new buffer, preferably using an RAII device such as a second vector.  Copies into it, and only if all of that succeeds, swap `*this` with the RAII device.  This is the cheapest way to do things, whether or not you want the strong guarantee, and you get it for free.

Case 1 is also inexpensive to maintain the strong guarantee.  The best way I know of is to first copy/move the new element into the middle of the new allocation.  If that succeeds, then move the elements from the old buffer and swap.

**More Detail Than You Probably Want**

[libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) accomplishes all 3 cases with the same algorithm.  To accomplish this, two tools are used:

1. [`std::move_if_noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)
2. A non-std `vector`-like container where the data is contiguous, but can start at a non-zero offset from the beginning of the allocated buffer.  libc++ calls this thing `split_buffer`.

Assuming the reallocation case (the non-reallocation case is trivial), the `split_buffer` is constructed with a reference to this `vector`'s allocator, and with twice the capacity of this `vector`, and with its starting position set to `this->size()` (though the `split_buffer` is still `empty()`).

Then the new element is copied or moved (depending on which `push_back` overload we are talking about) to the `split_buffer`.  If this fails, the `split_buffer` destructor undoes the allocation.  If it succeeds, then the `split_buffer` now has `size() == 1`, and the `split_buffer` has room for exactly `this->size()` elements prior to its first element.

Next the elements are moved/copied *in reverse order* from `this` to the `split_buffer`.  [`move_if_noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept) is used for this, which has a return type of either `T const&` or `T&&` exactly as we need as specified by the 3 cases above.  On each successful move/copy, the `split_buffer` is doing a `push_front`.  If successful, the `split_buffer` now has `size() == this->size()+1`, and its first element is at a zero offset from the beginning of its allocated buffer.  If any move/copy fails, `split_buffer`'s destructor destructs whatever is in the `split_buffer` and deallocates the buffer.

Next the `split_buffer` and `this` swap their data buffers.  This is a `noexcept` operation.

Finally the `split_buffer` destructs, destructing all of its elements, and deallocating its data buffer.

No try-catches needed.  There is no extra expense.  And everything works as specified by C++11 (and summarized above).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what do you actually mean by the "basic" guarantee?

Comment: "basic guarantee" is an informal term (not a standard term) that means that you won't get undefined behavior.  You won't leak memory.  But if you catch the exception and inspect the state of the `vector`, that state is unspecified.  There is no guarantee for example that the elements have, or have not been moved from.  It is a valid `vector` with an unspecified state that you are free to inspect.

Comment: So basically a possibly-throwable move ctor is used only in the case when there is no copy ctor, and if it throws then you may get in trouble, is this correct?

Comment: *"If `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value` is true, move, else"* I wonder if this is a defect. IIRC, there's been a discussion some time ago on the isocpp mailing list that an allocator might intervene (e.g. throw an exception in `construct` even though the move constructor of the type is `noexcept`).

Comment: Correct.  Though as long as you understand that you only have the basic guarantee, you have enough information to keep yourself out of trouble.

Comment: @dyp:  I agree it looks like there is a defect. [allocator.requirements] should state that an allocator's construct function should not propagate any exception except those thrown from within the constructor of `c`.  I looked in the current issues list and did not see such an issue.  If you would like to open such an issue, here are the instructions:  http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue

Comment: ISTR discussions about an optional extra case (1.5 or 2.5) where we default construct elements in the new buffer, and if that succeeded, we noexcept-swap them with those in the old buffer.

Comment: Howard, I looked through your explanation of how libc++ implements this operation, but I do not understand why this trickery with a `split_buffer` is necessary. Isn't merely allocating a regular chunk of memory using whatever growth function, constructing the element at the right place and using an allocator aware `std::uninitialized_copy` with `move_if_noexcept_iterator`s enough (using proper try-cleanup blocks)? My gut feeling tells me introducing a different data structure is overkill for this. I also do not understand why you emphasized _in reverse order_.

Comment: @orlp:  My strong preference is to do things without try/catch when the catch would need to rethrow the exception.  The reason for this is that on the platforms I use, if the program terminates from an uncaught exception, one gets a nice stack trace from the point of the **last** throw.  If there are try/catch/re-throw blocks on that path, the stack trace starts at the last re-throw, not from the point of the original throw.  Thus using RAII in place of try/catch/re-throw leads to better stack dumps (on my platforms of interest).

Comment: @orlp: The reverse order of construction was used just to simplify `~split_buffer()`.  The way I have it coded, `~split_buffer()` always has to deal only with one contiguous block of constructed elements.  Certainly one could add more info to `split_buffer` to have it track say two contiguous blocks of constructed elements.  But I was not motivated to do so.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks for your explanation, that seems like a valid concern. I'm in the process of developing a container myself (a contiguous std::deque, or a std::vector with fast insertion on either end), and trying to get all details right. Once I'm in the final stages I'll see if I can replace all uses of `try { /* */; } catch(...) { /* */; throw; }` with RAII if it helps stack dumps. In case you are mildly interested: https://github.com/orlp/devector The docs are reasonably done, the code is still heavily in development.

Comment: @orlp:  Thanks for the link.  Looks very interesting.  It actually looks a lot like what my `split_buffer` was aiming at, but was never fully developed.  I think this is a valuable data structure, and wish you the best of luck with it.  Fwiw, one of the things I needed to do with `split_buffer` was manually position the start position in a new container of non-zero capacity.  I never felt like I got a really good API for that part.  Perhaps you will have some inspiration in that department that eluded me. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant How I approached this problem is as following: I have two reserve functions, `reserve_back(n)` and `reserve_front(n)` that respectively attempt to increase `capacity_back()` and `capacity_front()` to at least `n`. I wanted `devector` to be an (almost) drop-in replacement for `std::vector`, so `reserve(n)` is an alias for `reserve_back(n)` (similarly `capacity()` -> `capacity_back()`). Finally I added an overload `reserve(front, back)` that behaves like `reserve_front(front); reserve_back(back);`, but only reallocates at most once. This is the function that solves your use case.

Answer (score 3):

That is what is happening and it can be expensive. It was [decided](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler) that the strong guarantee of push_back is more important than the performance from move semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Reallocations are expensive, yes. That's why the cost of reallocation is amortized over the many calls of `std::vector::push_back`.

Most commonly it's done by allocating new block of size given by multiplying old size by some constant factor (for example 1.5 or 2) - like 1,2,4,8,16,32,...

When reallocating, `std::vector` allocates new block, copies the elements, destroys the old elements and deallocates the old block. In case of failure (thrown exception) we can simply abort the process of copying and start destroying the copied elements - so the cost in the worst case is `2*(n-1)+d`, where `d` is the cost of deallocation (we copy `n-1` elements, when copying the n-th element, exception is thrown, so we destroy `n-1` elements, and deallocate the new block)

Note the above applies when moves are not `noexcept`. If moves are `noexcept`, the only possible point of failure is allocation of the new memory block (since destructors are required to be `noexcept`), and the reallocation process is simpler and faster.

You can reduce the performance impact of reallocations by using different container (like `std::deque`, where the issue does not exist) or by using `std::vector::reserve` beforehand (this requires knowing an estimate for the element count).